# Page refresh with post data javascript

Tags: javascript, post

I want to reload the page with automatically sending post data again, without warning the user if they actually want to send again.

This doesnt work, as it shows the warning:

```
location.reload();
```

And this doesnt work at all, as it just makes a GET request:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Comment: You don't need javascript to accomplish this. Use a `form` element.

Comment: can i have a prompt() in a form when clicking submit?

Comment: Indeed you can. Just make sure to submit the form afterwards